# Is there a way to use .Net 4.0 System.Threading.Tasks class in .Net 3.5 or .Net3.0 versions?

Tags: .net, multithreading

I get to understand the .Net 4.0 provides a better approach on multi-threading with tasks. Is there a way that it is possible to do the same approach in .Net 3.5 or .Net 3.0.

Thanks,
Priya.R

Answer (score 3):

I believe the Reactive Extensions for .NET (Rx) include some of the .NET 4.0 concurrency bits.

So that might be worth a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx

Check out the System.Threading.dll

Comment: You believed correctly. They backported  that API to use with Rx.

Comment: Yeah, we've been using Rx since it was released for Silverlight and I vaguely remembered coming across the Tasks namespaces while poking through the assemblies. It probably won't perform as well as .NET 4.0 though because it doesn't use the new work stealing thread pool.

Comment: System.Threading.dll was removed from Rx in a recent version: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/rx/thread/a55a0b30-ff76-40f5-a3d5-7b7496c4ef35

Answer (score 0):

No, if you want to use `System.Threading.Tasks`, you will have to upgrade to .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting .NET 3.5, then downloded rx for 3.5 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24940) after installation add **System.Threading.dll** in References.

now you can use directive **using System.Threading.Tasks**;

i hope this may help you...